# Oracle PL equivalent of foreach-loop

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

I need to loop over about 10 strings, which are all known to me in advance -- I don't need to `SELECT` them from anywhere.

I attempted:

```sql
BEGIN
    FOR tab IN ('one', 'two', 'three')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || tab;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But that does not work (`LOOP` is unexpected)...

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
declare
   type t_strings is table of varchar2(100);
   strings t_strings:=t_strings('one','two','three');
begin
   for i in 1..strings.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line(strings(i));
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Results:

```
one
two
three
```

Or you can use your own short-cut functions:
http://orasql.org/2017/10/02/plsql-functions-iterate-and-keys-for-associative-arrays/

Btw, Oracle 21 has some new features for FOR-LOOP:

- [1.1.1 PL/SQL Extended Iterators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/release-changes.html#GUID-60026B49-A592-4F2A-83FC-5C755695F850)
- [FOR LOOP Iteration Enhancements in Oracle Database 21c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/for-loop-iteration-enhancements-21c)

So it can be rewritten as:

```sql
declare
   type t_strings is table of varchar2(100);
begin
   for str in values of t_strings('one','two','three') loop
      dbms_output.put_line(str);
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

"almost real" foreach loop:

```
declare 
    type tabList is table of varchar2(32);
    tabs tabList := tabList ('one', 'two', 'three');
    curr varchar2(32) := tabs.first;
begin
    <<foreach>> loop exit foreach when curr is null;
        execute immediate 'create table '||tabs(curr)||' (col char(1))';
        execute immediate 'drop table '||tabs(curr)||' purge';
        curr := tabs.next (curr);
    end loop;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: `<<angle>>` brackets?

Comment: @MikhailT. [<<label>>](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/block.html#GUID-9ACEB9ED-567E-4E1A-A16A-B8B35214FC9D)

Answer (score 2):

```
begin
for tab_rec in (  select 'abc' val from dual
            union 
            select '123' val from dual )
loop
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || tab_rec.val;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Sigh, what a bottomless fount of hideous hackery `dual` is, is not it?